# Javascript filtering on keyup

Tags: javascript, filter, filtering

Here is my current HTML table:

```
<table class="table table-index">
    <thead>
        <tr class="filters">
            <th><input type="text" id="search_table" class="form-control company-id" placeholder="ID"></th>
            <th><input type="text" id="search_table" class="form-control" placeholder="Organization"></th>
            <th><input type="text" id="search_table" class="form-control" placeholder="Contact"></th>
            <th><input type="text" id="search_table" class="form-control" placeholder="Title"></th>
            <th><input type="text" id="search_table" class="form-control" placeholder="City"></th>
            <th><input type="text" id="search_table" class="form-control" placeholder="State"></th>
            <th><input type="text" id="search_table" class="form-control" placeholder="email"></th>
            <th><input type="text" id="search_table" class="form-control" placeholder="contacted"></th>
            <th><input type="text" id="search_table" class="form-control" placeholder="hiring"></th>
            <th><input type="text" id="search_table" class="form-control" placeholder="hire_count"></th>
            <th>
                <div class="checkbox-inline">
                    <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox1" class="large" data-label-prepend="prefix">
                        <label for="checkbox1">Contacted</label>
                </div>
             </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>


    <tbody>
        <% @companies.each do |company| %>
        <tr>
            <td class="id"><%= company.id %></td>
            <td class="Organization"><%= link_to company.organization,
                    admin_company_path(company.id) %></td>
            <td class="contact"><%= company.name %></td>
            <td class="contact-title"><%= company.title %></td>
            <td class="city"><%= company.city %></td>
            <td class="state"><%= company.state %></td>
            <td class="email"><%= company.email %></td>
            <td class="contacted"><%= company.status %></td>
            <td class="hiring"><%= company.hiring %></td>
            <td class="hire_count"><%= company.hire_count %></td>
        </tr>
        <% end %>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Here is my `table_filtering.js` file:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($(".table-index").length > 0 ) {
        $('#search_table').keyup(function() {
            searchByColumn($(this).val());
        });

        function searchByColumn(searchVal) {
            var table = $('.table-index')
            table.find('tr').each(function(index, row){
                var allDataPerRow = $(row).find('td');
                if (allDataPerRow.length > 0) {
                    var found = false;
                    allDataPerRow.each(function(index, td) {
                        var regExp = new RegExp(searchVal, "i");

                        if(regExp.test($(td).text())) {
                            found = true
                            return false;
                        }
                  });

                  if(found === true) {
                      $(row).show();
                  }else {
                      $(row).hide();
                  }
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

The problem is that I'm only filtering by the first `$("#search_table")` which is the ID column but I'm not filtering by any of the text boxes. What can I do so that all of the text boxes are filtering? I also want users to be able to filter by multiple text boxes. So if a user puts in input in the city and title, results only by the city and title will show.

Also, is my current filtering compatible with will_paginate? Meaning... will results on other pages be searched through?

Comment: The filtering works so the id input only checks the first td, organization the second and contact the third, etc? and the showing results are the ones meeting all these filters or one of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case all you need to do is to change from using ids to classes.

```
<tr class="filters">
    <th>
        <input type="text" class="search_table form-control company-id" placeholder="ID" />
    </th>
    <!-- etc -->
```

and relevant JS part will use `.search_table` selector:

```
$('.search_table').keyup(function() {
    searchByColumn($(this).val());
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/CXuhR4ucd4bFKbrifVMp?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

I'm getting all the inputs with class `.form-control` and pass them to the function. Then check if the input has a value, if not it won't be taken into account. For each input only the same column index is searched (e.g. for `id` I only filter the `td` with `index=0` and so on. For each input rows not matching the value are given a class `hide` which has style of `display: none;`.

[**jsfiddle DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/samuraii/gxzkrm04/2/)

**jQuery:**

```
if ($(".table-index").length > 0) {
    $('.form-control').keyup(function () {
        var inputs = ($('.form-control'));
        searchByColumn(inputs);
    });

    function searchByColumn(inputs) {
        $('.table-index tr').removeClass('hide');
        var table = $('.table-index');
        inputs.each(function () {
            var idx = $(this).parent().index();
            var searchVal = $(this).val();
            if (searchVal != "") {
                table.find('tr').not('.hide').each(function (index, row) {
                    var allDataPerRow = $(row).find('td').eq(idx);
                    if (allDataPerRow.length > 0) {
                        var found = false;
                        allDataPerRow.each(function (index, td) {
                            var regExp = new RegExp(searchVal, "i");
                            if (regExp.test($(td).text())) {
                                found = true;
                                return false;
                            }
                        });
                        if (found === true) {
                            $(row).removeClass('hide');
                        } else {
                            $(row).addClass('hide');
                        }
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**CSS:**

```
tr.hide {
    display: none;
}
```

**Sidenote:**

- IDs should be unique, try to avoid giving different elements the same ID.